# How to make a keyword you look for return true when using it in text strings?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I found this dataset on kaggle that I wanted to do EDA on.

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/andrewmvd/data-scientist-jobs/data

quick overview: Dataset is scraped from glassdoor datascience job postings.
One of the columns is the job title, some of the jobs have "Senior" or relevant words to senior in it. Such as "Data Science Director" or "Senior Data Analyst".

I want to write code that returns 1 if keywords like Senior, Sr, Director, Lead etc... are in the job title.

Here is my attempt at the code so far

```
def seniority_level_(text):
    seniority_list = ["sr","senior","lead","director", "sr.","vp"]
    for i in seniority_list:
        if i in text.lower():
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
df_data["Senior level"] = df_data["Job Title"].apply(seniority_level_)
```

Now I use .apply in pandas on the Job title column to create a new column that is either 1 or 0, if 1, then Senior is in the job title, if 0 then it is not a senior position.

The problem with this is that it seems to only work on the first entry of the Job Title column that has Sr in the job title, but doesn't seem to work on any other entries in the column.

Where am I going wrong in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code arises from the use of the `return` statement within the loop. When Python executes the `return` statement, it immediately exits the `seniority_level_` function, returning a value based on the first item in the `seniority_list` only. Therefore, your function checks against only the first keyword ("sr") and ignores the rest.

```
def seniority_level_(text):
    seniority_list = ["sr", "senior", "lead", "director", "sr.", "vp"]
    for i in seniority_list:
        if i in text.lower():
            return 1
    return 0  # This will execute if none of the keywords are found

df_data["Senior level"] = df_data["Job Title"].apply(seniority_level_)
```

Comment: Thank you very much,
but it already executes the ```return``` statement in the for loop in your code and seems to still work anyway regardless. Why does what you did work and mine doesn't?

Comment: Yours does not work because your for loop never goes beyond the first entry (`sr`) as you hit a return whether it's contained in the job title or not.

Comment: It is the `return 0` in your code which is causing the problem. Notice how the answer above has this at a different indentation level and without `else`.

Comment: So what happens when you hit the return in this code? Doesn't it exit the function I have written too?

Answer (score -1):

With a regex:

```py
seniority_list = r"(sr|senior|lead|director|sr.|vp)"
df_data["Senior level"] = df_data["Job Title"].str.contains(seniority_list, case=False).astype(int)
```

Comment: Hi mate, this code doesn't work says ```first argument must be string or compiled pattern``` I like this approach as it uses regex, which is something I am working towards mastering.

Comment: My bad, I used the wrong variable name, please try the updated version.

Comment: There is a slight issue here and that is list in lowercase and the words in the job title are in capitalized, I will try to fix it.

Comment: Alright I fixed it, thanks a lot for this.

Comment: Have edited to make the match case insensitive.